# ZAP Spider not working in Angular SPA - How to setup Structural Parameters?

Tags: angular, security, single-page-application, zap, penetration-testing

I have ZAP setup and authenticated correctly, but when I spider it does not crawl any pages. My application is an SPA, client side rendered application. It is an angular app that communicates to a C# API, that I am running/testing on localhost.

I have read about [Structural Parameters](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/structparams/) but ZAP's website doesn't have any useful info on how to actually fill them out/set them up. My URLs are a bit strange, typically something like: `host/#/page_type/id/sub_page/id;param=X;param2=Y`. There is always a "#" after the host at the beginning of the URL. How can I add this to the structural param?

The app also loads pretty slowly, and I am worried that ZAP won't pick up links to crawl if they take 3 seconds to show up. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Nothing after the # is sent to the server, fragments are only handled client side. The default timeout is 20s, 3 should be just fine. I'd suggest using the AJAX Spider and seeing if it can navigate your app.

Comment: Note that the Ajax Spider has an `Reload Wait Time` config param which defaults to 1 second: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/ajax-spider/options/ you'll probably want to increase this for your app :)

Comment: Thank you both! I will test this out when possible, it seems like exactly what I need